Is there a way to get Only songs with "downloadable" = true via the Search endpoint?
Im trying to obtain a list of songs that have the download_url and downloadable = true.
I am also trying to obtain the top 5 songs of a genres.
The Search endpoint has a query parameter but the api reference doesn't have these examples.
Can someone provide me with one?
I tried using this:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/explorer/open-api#/search/get_tracks
Genre doesn't have a concrete list to check but it's less important that the check for the downloadable url not being null.
I cannot use an async solution nor the sdks provided nor any solution with a dependency.
